# how to set session in rest full api codeigniter

Tags: android, rest, api, session, codeigniter-3

I have a function to set session on API in CodeIgniter
this is my function :

```
function getAndroidId_post(){
        $android_id  = $this->post('android_id');
        $sess_data['android_id'] = $android_id;
        $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
        $this->response($sess_data,200);
    }
```

This function is used to record Android_id, I also made an Android application to send Android _id to the function. but when Android_id has been sent, but the Android_id session is still empty.

I display it in this way

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('android_id') ?>
```

Comment: Did you load the `session library` on your framework? On CI, you can add under `application/config/autoload.php` you will see `$autoload['libraries']` there add `session` to load it automatically like `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

Comment: load session library as autoload `config/autoload.php` 

use **$this->input->post('android_id');** to get what posted to your function